# Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync not working on Stand Alone iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm trying to my expo/react-native project to send push notifications to my server. It works on standalone Android, but not stand alone iPhone.

The standalone iPhone app never sends the token.

Since the app sends nothing without error, I tried removing:

`if (finalStatus !== 'granted') { return; }`

This didn't work either.

```
export async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync(token) {

  const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
    Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
  );
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;

  // Only ask if permissions have not already been determined, for iOS.
  if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    finalStatus = status;
  }

  // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
  if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
    return;
  }

  // Get the push token that uniquely identifies this device
  let expoToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

  // Post new push token to backend for user
  return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${str.ROOT_URL}/account/push/`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`
    },
    data: {
      "token": expoToken,
      "status": finalStatus
    }
  });

}
```

I expected the token to get sent to the backend, but nothing is sent on the standalone iOS app.

Please let me know if you know a workaround or had this issue before. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? my token is not sending to the backend either

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late to give an answer, but I spent 2 days to resolve it... I hope it helps somebody.

Instead this:

```
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
```

Try this:

```
import { Notifications } from "expo";
```

Comment: Hello, I am hoping you might be able to help me. I have changed my import to import Notifications from expo, but the getDevicePushTokenAsync() doesn't seem to be resolving. Any ideas why?

Comment: @kalculated Hello. Honestly I don't know. Make sure that expo is not ejected, but I guess this is miss suggestion.

Comment: No worries, I upgraded my SDK and fixed things